# Move equation in subfigure

Tags: equations, pdftex, import, subfig

I'd like to move an equation inside a figure environment.
It should appear slightly above the current place:

```
\documentclass[
    a4paper,
    11pt,
]{article}

% Needed for correct typography and encoding
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

% Allows including graphics
\usepackage{graphicx, import}

% Advanced Math-Environment and symbols
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{trfsigns}

\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{enumitem}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[H]
        \centering
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.25\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{normalsize}
                \import{bilder/}{Tiefpass.pdf_tex}
            \end{normalsize}
            \caption{}
            \label{fig: Tiefpass_Übertragungsfunktion}
        \end{subfigure}
        %\vspace{-0.5cm}
        \hspace{0.5cm}
        \begin{subfigure}[b]{0.7\textwidth}
            \centering
            \begin{equation}
            \begin{aligned}
            H(f) = \text{rect}_{2 f_{\mathrm{g}}}(f) \quad \Laplace \quad h(t) = 2\cdot f_{\mathrm{g}} \cdot \frac{\sin \left( 2 \pi f_{\mathrm{g}} t \right)}{2 \pi f_{\mathrm{g}} t}
            \end{aligned}
            \label{eq: Tiefpass}
            \end{equation}
            \caption{}
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{Übertragungsverhalten (\ref{fig: Tiefpass_Übertragungsfunktion}) und Impulsantwort (\ref{eq: Tiefpass}) eines idealen Tiefpasses im eindimensionalen Fall.}
        \label{fig: Tiefpass}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

So the equation should be somewhere here:
[image]

This is my pdf_tex-file:
[Tiefpass.pdf_tex](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a61lik0gvppxkqq/Tiefpass.pdf_tex?dl=0)

**EDIT**: This is what the pdf looks like:
[image]

Comment: Thank you for specifying the pdf-file. However, not everybody can or is willing to access the drop-box. // Suggestion: Perhaps it's sufficient to use a screenshot, which you can post here, to demonstrate how things may be done? If so, please add it do your question (via EDIT). // Please check also if you need each and every package for this specific problem ... and delete them from your code (minimalistic but complete for a compile).

Comment: Do you need `subfigure` at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently your image is wider than reserved space in `subfigure` environment, consequently it protrude right border of it.

You have two possibilities to solve your problem:

- include figure with `\includegraphics[width=\linewidth. ...]{Tiefpass}` where image can be `.pdf` or `.jpg` image format
- redraw images as i dan in second solution in MWE below:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
%---------------- show page layout. don't use in a real document!
\usepackage{showframe}
\renewcommand\ShowFrameLinethickness{0.15pt}
\renewcommand*\ShowFrameColor{\color{red}}
%---------------------------------------------------------------%
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclareMathOperator{\rect}{rect}
\DeclareMathOperator{\g}{\mathrm{g}}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\usepackage{trfsigns}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \includegraphics[width=\linewidth, valign=m]{example-image-duck}
\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{0.75\linewidth}
\begin{equation}\label{eq: Tiefpass}
H(f) = \rect_{2 f_{\mathrm{g}}}(f)
    \quad \Laplace \quad
h(t) = 2{\cdot}f_{\g}\dfrac{\sin( 2 \pi f_{\g} t)}{2 \pi f_{\g} t}
    \end{equation}
                \end{subfigure}
\caption{Übertragungsverhalten (\ref{fig: Tiefpass_Übertragungsfunktion}) und Impulsantwort (\ref{eq: Tiefpass}) eines idealen Tiefpasses im eindimensionalen Fall.}
        \label{fig: Tiefpass}
    \end{figure}    

    \begin{figure}[ht]
\begin{subfigure}{0.25\linewidth}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=-3pt,
arr/.style = {-Latex, semithick},
lbl/.style = {font=\footnotesize, text=black, below}
                        ]
\draw[arr]  (-1.5,0) -- (1.52,0);
\draw[arr]  (0,-0.6) -- (0,1.3) node[above] {$\abs{H}(f)$};
\draw[blue, very thick] (-1,0) node[lbl] {$-f_{\g}$} -- ++ (0,0.8)
                                              -| (1,0)  node[lbl] {$f_{\g}$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{subfigure}\begin{subfigure}{0.75\linewidth}
\begin{equation}\label{eq: Tiefpass}
H(f) = \rect_{2 f_{\mathrm{g}}}(f)
    \quad \Laplace \quad
h(t) = 2{\cdot}f_{\g}\dfrac{\sin( 2 \pi f_{\g} t)}{2 \pi f_{\g} t}
    \end{equation}
                \end{subfigure}
\caption{Übertragungsverhalten (\ref{fig: Tiefpass_Übertragungsfunktion}) und Impulsantwort (\ref{eq: Tiefpass}) eines idealen Tiefpasses im eindimensionalen Fall.}
        \label{fig: Tiefpass}
    \end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you very much!